# C++: Delete an 'auto' array

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator, auto

when creating an array like

```
auto a = new int[10][10];
```

how do I delete it afterwards?

```
delete a
```

or

```
delete[] a?
```

Regards,
VanDahlen

Comment: True, the example was bad.

Comment: Would it help you if it was written as `using T = int[10]; T * x = new T[10];`? What if you used `using T = int;` instead?

Comment: It's irrevelant that it's `auto`. You delete it as usual, with `delete []`.

Comment: whatever you create with `new[]` you destroy with `delete[]` irrelevant of `auto` or even if you assign it to `void *`

Answer (score 3):

Your "auto array" is actually a `int(*)[10]`, because that's what the 2D `new[]` gives you.

`auto` means you don't have to write the type yourself, but it's still there, hidden behind the scenes in the catacombs of reality.

**Regardless, just like anything else created via `new[]`, you must kill it with <strike>fire</strike> `delete[]`.**

Anyway, prefer `int* ptr = new int[10*10]`, I would. Or in this case just `int array[100]` :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Whoops

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: related: hmm, did they change the grace period rules? It used to be that your comment would have closed the grace period for edits (and I was fine with that) but there's no revision history being advertised for my answer now